# the right jquery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<div class="card">
     <a id="342">
     <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
     <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">Product title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Product desc.</p>
        <a href="details.php?id=342" class="btn btn-primary">More Details.....</a>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
     <a id="343">
     <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
     <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">Product title</h4>
         <p class="card-text">Product desc.</p>
        <a href="details.php?id=343" class="btn btn-primary">More Details.....</a>

     </div>
  </div>
```

what would the jquery selector be to select the image that is inside the card with an anchor of 343 that is passes in the url "localhost/products.php#343" replacing the ??? to execute the command

```
$(???).addClass("highlight");
```

to add the class highlight to the  element.

Comment: Do you want add class `hightlight` to img class??

Comment: What have you tried, after looking up jQuery documentation?

Comment: Note that in HTML4 and CSS2 (used by `querySelector`) `id` attribute could not start by a numeric. So even if it is now allowed in HTML5, and that jQuery handles it, it's still not a good idea to use it as some current APIs will break.

Comment: @Kaiido: Even if some APIs will break, only the most obscure ones (non-browser) will. The entire reason HTML5 relaxed the restrictions is because the vast majority of implementations never enforced the restrictions to begin with - in particular, no known version of any browser ever made ever did.

Comment: @BoltClock Are you saying that Document&Element's `querySelector[All]` are *"obscure APIs"*? I'm really sorry that these 4 methods still use the CSS2 syntax, but they do, and I can't do anything about it...

Comment: @Kaiido: Oh, so you're saying not to use numeric IDs because the selector syntax doesn't allow numeric idents. That's fine, but not at all related to compatibility issues, or even APIs for that matter. It's just how the CSS grammar has been designed. Escape the selector and you'll find that jQuery and all browsers will match the element just fine. Nothing is broken here.

Comment: Well `querySelector` is part of the WebAPI and I never talked about backwards compatibility no. Just saying that it's not a good idea to use it, even if HTML5 now allows it. About your edit, how do escape this selector? Even though I didn't really check, I guess jQuery's own selector's parser is smart enough to simply jump from any `#something` to faster `getElementById(something)`, but I also said that jQuery does handle it.

Answer (score 2):

`$("#343").siblings("img.card-img-top").addClass("highlight");`

This works well, if I understood question correctly.

Comment: Thanks. If I was going to write the command so that it would take whatever the value of the hash is I could use "var hashID = window.location.hash; $(hashID).siblings("img.card-img-top").addClass("highlight");"

Comment: @ArtooSmith Oh, what I wrote was a different answer with your expected.. but I'm glad you got what you want. :)

Comment: didn't seem to work.  I was trying to take the value of the hash from the URL and then add the 'highlight' class to the <img> element of the card with the ID passed at the end of the URL.   I store the hash inside a variable "hashID" and tried "$(hashID).siblings("img.card-img-top").addClass("highlight");"  Used the "inspect element" debugger in Firefox and didn't see the class added to the <img> element.

Comment: @ArtooSmith is there no problem in sequence? If document loaded first, `hashID` has not value then. Try to check when `hashID` get the value by using console. Or if there are any problem, maybe comment of @Kaiido is right. (cf. id attribute could not start by a numeric).

Comment: @ArtooSmith Though id attribute could not start by a numeric, you can handle this. When you got numeric hash value from URL, add some characters in front of numeric value, like `hash343`. And put this into id, you will be able to solve it.

Comment: @ArtooSmith I'm not sure if this link can solve your problem, but I think both your problem and explanation of this link have some similarities. https://css-tricks.com/add-id-to-body/